# How to change from Personal Apple Developer to Enterprise?

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

My iOS developer licence is expiring as of 1st Feb and I was wondering if I can switch to enterprise licence or should I do that from beginning? I wish to keep my Apple IDs and apps...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may have misunderstood what the Enterprise iOS Developer Program is all about which is not an upgrade to the Standard plan you're enrolled to. The Enterprise license is mainly intended for companies and organisations that are creating proprietary iOS apps for internal distribution (In-house). The main benefit is that you can deploy private apps to iOS devices without needing to register UDIDs in the provisioning portal as you do when distributing Ad-hoc builds. On the other hand you're not allowed to distribute apps on the App Store.

Only companies and organizations with a Dun & Bradstreet (D-U-N-S) Number can enroll to the Enterprise developer program.

Take a look at the following [FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html) and compare the Standard and Enterprise developer program [here](https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/ios/)

Comment: thanks a lot :) tell me one more thing: to change apple id that licence is assigned to can I change only ID or should I enroll for new licence?

Comment: You'll need to create a new AppleID and separately enroll for a new license.

Comment: doesn't it mean that with my licence B (new one) I won't be able to update/develop/sell old apps created with licence A (team agent, who is currently not working with my firm)?

Comment: With an Enterprise license you cannot sell/update apps on the App Store at all. You can just distribute Ad-Hoc and In-house applications for internal use. The new AppleID you create for the Enterprise plan has no connect with your existing AppleID.

Comment: yep, got that so I checked your answer, but in comment with A/B licences I meant personal programs - so it's better to renew old profile (team agent who is not working anymore) or new mine and make me somehow team agent in firm?

Comment: @Tomas Camin 
 
Can i change Apple developer Enterprise Program to normal Apple developer Program (Organization) so that I can submit apps in Appstore.

Comment: No, enterprise and standard dev programs are completely separated and AFAIK you cannot switch from one to another.

Answer (score 2):

Switch from a Personal to Enterprise means that you will lose the ability to distribute app via the App Store.

Also Enterprise license are ment for big companies to distribute app in-house, meaning apps for employees only.